# inline javascript popup function not working in IE11 and below

Tags: javascript, html, function, internet-explorer-11, target

I have an inline html link like this:

```
<a href="javascript:myPopup('https://twitter.com/share?url=http://website.com')" target="_blank">my link</a>
```

and this is the function it should execute:

// share popup

```
function myPopup(url) {
    var leftPosition, topPosition;
    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((566 / 2) + 10);
    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((576 / 2) + 50);
    window.open(url, "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 576, width = 566, resizable = 0,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no")
}
```

It works fine everywhere except on IE11 and below.
in IE11 and below the link opens in a new tab

[image]

I initially thought this was because of popup blocking or something, but i don't think it's the case. I've changed the `href=""` into `href="myPopup('...')"` but it didn't work.

any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Can't you see what URL you are trying to open? Use onclick.

Comment: it works! thanks. i'm this bad with js :)

Comment: actually this works on IE but not on iOS...

Answer (score 0):

Your html code is wrong, use the below code

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript::myPopup('https://twitter.com/share?url=http://website.com');" target="_blank">my link</a>

function myPopup(url) {
    var leftPosition, topPosition;
    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((566 / 2) + 10);
    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((576 / 2) + 50);
    window.open(url, "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 576, width = 566, resizable = 0,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no")
}
```